# No such file or directory using a date variable in bash

Tags: bash

Currently trying to write a Bash script to automatically create a `.txt` file with the name being today's date (Using `NOW_FILE` var), and then append today's date to that file (Using `NOW_STRING` var).

Attached is the script:

```
SAVE_PATH='~/Desktop/' # Set the save path               
NOW_FILE=$(date +"%B_%d_%Y") # Date used for the file name        
NOW_STRING=$(date +"%B %d %Y %r") # Date used within the entry      

echo $NOW_STRING > $SAVE_PATH$NOW_FILE.txt # Output the date to the file 
$EDITOR $SAVE_PATH$NOW_FILE.txt # Open the file with the default editor
```

If I execute the script, the error I get is:

```
 ~    echo $NOW_STRING > $SAVE_PATH$NOW_FILE.txt 
-bash: ~/Desktop/March_08_2015.txt: No such file or directory
```

However, if I take the variables out, and directly execute the code sans vars, like this:

`echo $(date +"%B %d %Y %r") > ~/Desktop/$(date +"%B_%d_%Y").txt`

I have no problems appending the date to the file's first line.

I suck at Bash, so maybe I am missing something in my script, like not separating my variables from non-var strings..

Comment: `SAVE_PATH=~/'Desktop/'` with the tilde unquoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `~` expansion. It's hot happening with your script as is.

```
SAVE_PATH="$HOME/Desktop/"
```

should do the trick. Make sure you quote that variable everywhere if the home path could contain whitespace (so quote it everywhere to be safe).

Alternatively, you can use:

```
SAVE_PATH=~/Desktop/
```

or

```
SAVE_PATH=~/"Some Path With Spaces/"
```

From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html), §3.5.2 *Tilde expansion*:

> If a word begins with an **unquoted** tilde character (‘~’), all of the characters up to the first unquoted slash (or all characters, if there is no unquoted slash) are considered a tilde-prefix. If none of the characters in the tilde-prefix are quoted, the characters in the tilde-prefix following the tilde are treated as a possible login name. If this login name is the null string, the tilde is replaced with the value of the HOME shell variable. If HOME is unset, the home directory of the user executing the shell is substituted instead. Otherwise, the tilde-prefix is replaced with the home directory associated with the specified login name.
>
> [...] (info about `~+` and `~-`)